# How to define custom Iterable types in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to extend the generic [`Iterable` interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#iterable-interface) by implementing the [[Symbol.iterator] generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator).

But desire to return different types; let's say I aim to allow this signature:

```
let [state, setState] = myObject; // myObject is not an array, but an iterable
```

To support this, what generic type do I need to give to Iteable?

```
interface MyObjectsInterface<T, E> extends Iterable<??> {}
```

Here is how it will be assigned:

```
myObject[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
    yield myObject.state;
    yield myObject.setState;
    yield myObject...;
  }
```

How can I type this well with typescript ?

Comment: This isn't currently possible, see [ms/TS#42033](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42033) for the relevant feature request.  Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668662/how-to-define-custom-iterable-types-in-typescript#comment131793505_74668662) @jcalz I don't think it's the same issue. OP is trying to destructure an iterable's yielded values, which requires invoking the iterator (e.g. spread `...`, `for...of`, etc.)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668662/how-to-define-custom-iterable-types-in-typescript#comment131794023_74668662) Actually, nvm: I was wrong to exclude [array destructuring as a supported pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#using_array_destructuring_on_any_iterable). I agree with your comment.

Comment: Until TS supports this pattern... does the example code represent your real data? What if — instead — you added getter property values to an actual array to act as proxies to the elements in the desired indexes (e.g. `state` -> `obj[0]`, `setState` -> `obj[1]`, etc.)? Here's a quick and dirty example to illustrate: https://tsplay.dev/wOxGdN That code could obviously be improved / made functional, etc. but the downside is that the object also inherits all of the array prototype methods.

Comment: hello @jcalz, So it isn't possible to do so ... okay i get it.. sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no support for a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)-like [`Iterable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#iterable-interface)  in TypeScript.  There's an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#42033](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42033).  It's marked as Awaiting More Feedback, meaning they need more community engagement that describes compelling use cases before they consider implementing.  There isn't much engagement there, so if you want to see this, you might want to go there, give it a , and explain why you need this (and why using just an actual array isn't good enough for you).

---

It is currently not even possible to write a type that works this way, since calls to the `Iterator`'s `next()` method would have to mutate the state of the iterator.  The only time a method call currently mutates the state of the object on which it's called is with an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), but those cannot return values at all, at least without [microsoft/TypeScript#40562](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40562).

And even if that were implemented, those assertion methods could only *narrow* the type of the iterator... but tuple-like iterables would have to be able to change to arbitrary result types that are not necessarily getting narrower for each call.  So then you'd also need "mutable" or "session" types, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#41339](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41339).

So then if both of those were implemented, then a `TupleLikeIterable<T extends any[]>` type could be written down.  And *then* you'd need to make the spread operator act on that in the desired way.  Seems like a lot of hoops to jump through, and none of those GitHub issues have much activity, so I'm not optimistic that this will get done anytime soon.

Still, if you care about this a lot, it wouldn't *hurt* to engage with the relevant GitHub issues.  But if I were you I'd try to make arrays work for your use case since those are well-supported.

Comment: Yeah understood, thanks a lot for the detailed replay.
So i ll end up using a toArray() method that can be removed later if typescript really supports this. Also, I ll keep the iterator for manual typing.

Thanks again, really appreciate it.